# VBA code returning #value error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to display the colour from the conditional formatting in excel.
In excel I simply use =CheckColour(B5) for example, and when I hit return it works. However, when I ask the sheet to calculate, the function gives #VALUE! and I don't know where I've gone wrong. Any help is appreciated as I'm a beginner at VBA. Thanks

```
    Function CheckColour(range)
        If range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        CheckColour = "Red"
        ElseIf range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 130, 59) Then
        CheckColour = "Green"
        Else
        CheckColour = "Amber"
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your signature would be much more explicit if it were `Public Function CheckColour(ByVal target As Range) As String` - right now it's implicitly public, `range` is implicitly `ByRef` and `Variant`, and the function implicitly returns a `Variant`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mat

Answer (score 6):

Yep, because:

> Note that the DisplayFormat property *does not work in user defined functions*. For example, in a worksheet function that returns the interior color of a cell, you use a line similar to: Range(n).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex. When the worksheet function executes, it returns a #VALUE! error. [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx).

Instead use:

```
range.Interior.Color
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, so is there any way I can take the conditional formatting colour and display it as a word, say red, green etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

This (simplified example) seems to work for me:

```
Public Function CheckColour(src As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    CheckColour = src.Parent.Evaluate("GetColor(" & src.Address(False, False) & ")")
End Function

Public Function GetColor(src As Range)
    GetColor = src.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function
```